# what is the difference between ` ` and ' '?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Hey guys i want to know that what is the difference between these two type of single quotes` and '

i tried to execute the below command with ` then it worked

```
axios.get(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.userName}`)
      .then(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
      });
```

but when i tried to run the same command using '' it doesnt work

```
axios.get('https://api.github.com/users/${this.state.userName}')
          .then(resp => {
            console.log(resp);
          });
```

Comment: Please read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Comment: In general, if you follow the prescribed syntax of a language, and it works, why would you change the syntax and then complain that nothing works?

Comment: There must be a zillion duplicates of this question here.

Answer (score 5):

The first is called **[template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)** added in the **ES6** - It first evaluates the given **embedded expressions**, gets the results and replaces the expressions with the results. In the `${}` you give expressions (variable, function call, ...), and it creates a string replacing the `${expression}` part with the result.

This code part

```js
var str = 'text';
var template = `Some ${str}`; // `str` is a expression which returns the value

console.log(template);
```

is equivalent of concatenation of strings.

```js
var str = 'text';
var template = 'Some ' + str; // Just concatenate the strings

console.log(template);
```

Template literals also allow you to create multi-line strings

```js
const multiLine = `This is a multi-
line text`;

console.log(multiLine);
```

Answer (score 3):

Backticks (`) are used to define [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literal) strings in JavaScript since ES6. These are used to use inline variables as well as declare multiline strings, previously not possible without concatenation (+).

Eg:

```
var name = 'John';
var string1 = 'My name is ' + name;   //ES5
var string2 = `My name is ${name}`;   //ES6
```

also can be used to declare multiline strings:

```
var longString = `this is a
                  really
                  long
                  multiline
                  string`;
```

**EDIT** Regarding my multiline example, template literals preserve whitespace. So the example won't be stored as you think it would. This link http://2ality.com/2016/05/template-literal-whitespace.html would be useful on that end.

Answer (score 1):

The first one `` is template literal or back ticks, where the second `''` is single quotes

Template literal can be used for multi line and may use "interpolation" to insert the content of variables along `$`

With quotes `''` this will require a string concatenation.

In your case it is used as interpolation

```js
console.log(`Hello I am 


template literal `)

console.log("Hello I am" +

  " quotes")
```

Answer (score -1):

It's not working as ' works for literals, so you probably getting what you typed literaly, on the other hand other kind of quotes let you develope a custom spresion